# Animated HTTP request visualisation on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, visualization

This is more a question to appease my memory in trying to remember what it was I saw a while ago.

I remember being introduced to a realtime server visualisation tool that showed the current requests that Apache was handling in a kind of fireworks effect on screen.  Each request/group of requests would be shot across the screen in varying colours.

I can't for the life for me remember what is was called and hunting around here and Google has left me empty handed.  Just wondering if anybody else was able to plug this gem from the memory and ease my pain!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Fudgie](http://www.fudgie.org/) on your Apache log files.

Comment: That's the one!